# How to solve Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException?

Tags: java, processing

After solving my previous error, here comes another NPE for this code:

```
public void displayCircles() {
    for (Circle menu : circles) {
        if (menu.getX() < defaultCircles[pulseCircle].getX() + 0.5 && 
            menu.getX() > defaultCircles[pulseCircle].getX() - 0.5 && 
            menu.getY() < defaultCircles[pulseCircle].getY() + 0.5 && 
            menu.getY() > defaultCircles[pulseCircle].getY() - 0.5) 
            {
                choiceCircle = menu;
                pulsingEffect(menu);
            }
```

The third line of the above mentioned codes are giving me NPE. Any ideas?

defaultCircles:

```
Circle[] defaultCircles = new Circle[circles.length];

void polygon(int n, float cx, float cy, float r) {
    float angle = 210.0f / n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        circles[i] = new Circle(i + 1, cx + r * cos(radians(angle * i)), cy + r * sin(radians(angle * i)));
        defaultCircles[i] = new Circle(i + 1, cx + r * cos(radians(angle * i)), cy + r * sin(radians(angle * i)));
    }
}
```

pulseCircle:

```
void findPulseCircle() {
    float max = circles[0].getY();
    for (int i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
        if (circles[i].getY() > max) {
            max = circles[i].getY();
            pulseCircle = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Need more clues to answer!

Comment: Show how/where you have declared and initialized `defaultCircles[]` and `pulseCircle`.

Comment: @csmckelvey updated with additional codes!

Comment: @SazzadurRahaman  updated with additional codes!

Comment: Are these all in the same class? Maybe you should just post _all_ your code that you are using in one chunk instead of just posting individual methods. Also, I still don't see where you declare `pulseCircle`.

Comment: Show your Circle code!

Comment: Please post the stack trace

Comment: I think it will be much easier if you post code that we can run (rather than guess how Circle might have been implemented)